# Fixed header and sidebar pushing content below them

Tags: html, css, grid

I've created a fixed side nav bar and header and i'd like to create a grid within the content section of the page, however, when i add in any main content, it pushes below the fixed side bar and does not show from just below the header.

I've been scrolling through stack and google to see if i can fix the issue, but none of though solutions has worked.

I've made a code pen for visuals and seeing the code:
https://codepen.io/nyxerian/pen/ZEBKMJg

As you'll see the h2 title should be in line with the Home button at the top of the screen.

What am I missing?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="basic.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/js/all.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- start: SIDEBAR NAV AND HEADER -->
        <div class='fixed header'></div>
        <div class='fixed side'>
            <img class="smartlogo" src="PNG1.png" alt="smart">
            <nav class="sidebar">
                <div class="text"></div>
                <br>
                <ul>
                  <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home" style="color:#2DAAD6;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-handshake fa-fw" style="color: #2DAAD6;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Sell</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-chart-line" style="color: #2DAAD6;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dashboards</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-boxes" style="color: #2DAAD6;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Inventory</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-credit-card" style="color: #2DAAD6;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Payments</a></li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#" class="lead-btn"><i class="far fa-folder-open" style="color: #2DAAD6;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Leads</a>
                    <ul class="lead-show">
                      <li><a href="#">Referrals</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"></i>Management</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-users" style="color: #2DAAD6;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Teams</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-clipboard" style="color: #2DAAD6;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Reporting</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-tools" style="color: #2DAAD6;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Settings</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
        </div>
        <div class='scrollable'></div>  



        <script>
            $('.lead-btn').click(function () {
            $('nav ul .lead-show').toggleClass('show')
            $('nav ul .first').toggleClass('rotate')
          })     
          
          $('nav ul li').click(function () {
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
          })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Nordstern', Helvetica;
}

.scrollable {
  height: 2000px;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

.header {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;

  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #436c89,
    #6ca1cd,
    #60b9c0
  ) !important;
}

.smartlogo {
  width: 140px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.side {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 240px;
  background-color: #e7e6e6;
}
.sidebar {
  height: 80%;
  width: 240px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #e7e6e6;
  margin-top: 85px;
}
.sidebar.show {
  left: 0px;
}
.sidebar .text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 65px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: left;
  background: #e7e6e6;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
nav ul {
  background: #e7e6e6;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
  line-height: 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
nav ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}
nav ul li a {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
}
nav ul li.active a {
  color: black;
  background: #e7e6e6;
  border-left-color: #60b9c0;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
}
nav ul ul {
  position: static;
  display: none;
}
nav ul .lead-show.show {
  display: block;
}
nav ul .serv-show.show1 {
  display: block;
}
nav ul ul li {
  line-height: 42px;
  border-top: none;
}
nav ul ul li a {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  padding-left: 80px;
}
nav ul li.active ul li a {
  color: Black;
  background: #e7e6e6;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
  color: black !important;
  background: #ffffff !important;
}
nav ul li a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}
nav ul li a span.rotate {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-180deg);
}

i {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Your .scrollable class has a height of 5000px -- updating to `.scrollable { margin: 100px auto 0; }` seems to fix it

Comment: Your scrollable class CSS gives a height of 2000px; at least remove it and add a margin-top on it.

Comment: Thank you! very much!